# Need to show progress bar while page loads

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript.

I am having a html which shows a report graph.

It takes 5-10 secs for the report to generate in html.

I want to show progress bar before the report generates.

Comment: Do you want an actual "progess" bar....or just a "working" icon to display?

Comment: just to show the progress in work

Comment: You will not be able to achieve this using JavaScript alone.  You would have to callback using Ajax and poll the status...and for something that loads in 5-10 seconds it isn't worth the effort.  In my opinion, you should simply display a "loading" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an animated gif show by default, when your graph is done loading then hide it. Does your loading funciton have a function callback option? if it does, do this here.
Otherwise, have the loading icon with a low z-index overlapping your graph, give the graph a higher z-index. vwalah.

If you're tracking % loaded, you can have a setup like so:

```
<div id='progress-bar-total'>
   <div id='progress-bar-percent'></div>
</div>
```

Have continuous calls to a function that does something like this:

```
function updateProgress(bytesRead, bytesTotal){
   var current = (bytesRead/bytesTotal) + "%";
   $("#progress-bar-percent").css("width", current);
}
```

Comment: I think the PO wants to know how to show progress, not just showing its being loaded.

Comment: Oh -- you want to track progress percantages OP?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div with background image as the loader image.

Show this div in the loading and hide the graph. After loading the graph hide the loader div and show the graph

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to javascript i wouldn't try takling a progress bar. I sugest you go with a simple working icon. Use an animated gif created from http://www.ajaxload.info/ and display that while you build your table in a hidden div. when you have finished building the table, show the hidden div and hide the loading icon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can achieve this using only JavaScript, but you could check for [this script](http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/progress.htm) which checks if all the images are loaded, showing a progress bar. 
Alternatively, as other people said, you could use a loading gif ([make one here](http://www.ajaxload.info/)) that hides after your page has been loaded.

I've only seen great progress bars when using Flash, but I believe it's not your case to use this technology.